# Why foldr works on infinity list?

Tags: haskell, recursion, fold

This function may work on infinity association lists, and it is easy to find out why:

```
findKey :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
findKey key [] = Nothing  
findKey key ((k,v):xs) = if key == k  
                         then Just v  
                         else findKey key xs
```

When it find the key, it returns `Just v`, stopping the recursion.
Now look at this another implementation:

```
 findKey' :: (Eq k) => k -> [(k,v)] -> Maybe v  
 findKey' key = foldr (\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Just v else acc) Nothing
```

How does the compiler/interpreter know that when the key matches k, it can return it?

```
 *Main> findKey' 1 $ zip [1..] [1..]
```

returns `Just 1`

When it finds that `key == k`, it returns `Just v`. Why does the recursion stop there, allowing us to do such things with infinity association lists?

Comment: Evaluate it manually and see for yorself.

Comment: `acc` is  not an accumulator (from the left); it stands for the recursive result (from the right), so better to call it `r`, to avoid the cognitive dissonance.

Comment: @WillNess, did you mean that when we use foldl/foldl' we should call the "acc" really acc, and when we use foldr we should call it r, cause it is the recursive part of the function?

Comment: @FtheBuilder on the second thought, basically, yes, that's it. :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the function passed to `foldr` does not always evaluate the `acc` parameter, i.e. it is lazy in that parameter.

For example,

```
(\(k,v) acc -> if 1 == k then Just v else acc) (1,"one") (error "here be dragons!")
```

will return `"one"` without even attempting to evaluate the `error` expression.

Moreover, `foldr` by definition satisfies:

```
foldr f a (x:xs) = f x (foldr f a xs)
```

If `x:xs` is infinite, but `f` does not use its second argument, then `foldr` can return immediately.

In your example, `f` evaluates its second element if and only if the first argument is not the wanted association. This means that the association list will only be evaluated only enough to find the `key` association.

If you like to experiment, try this instead:

```
foldr (\(k,v) acc -> case acc of
          Nothing -> if key == k then Just v else acc
          Just y  -> if key == k then Just v else acc) Nothing
```

The `case` looks redundant, since the function returns the same thing in both branches. *However*, this demands the evaluation of `acc` breaking the code on infinite lists.

Another thing you might want to try

```
foldr (:) [] [0..]
```

This basically rebuilds the infinite list as it is.

```
foldr (\x xs -> x*10 : xs) [] [0..]
```

This multiplies everything by `10`, and is equivalent to `map (*10) [0..]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, your example helped a lot. Just a little point: So considering that `foldr f a (x:xs) = f x (foldr f a xs)` if it was instead `foldr f a (x:xs) = f (foldr f a xs) x`, it wouldn't work on infinity lists?

Comment: @FtheBuilder If `f` needs to fully evaluate the exact value of the first argument (like in your example `\(k,v) acc -> if k == 1 then ... else ...`), then it wouldn't work. However, if `f` doesn't need to evaluate it (e.g. `\pair acc -> acc`) then it should work.

Comment: @mucaho Uhhmm, so, it only evaluates the argument (doesn't matter the order) if it is needed inside its logics basically??

Comment: @FtheBuilder Yes, that's the gist of lazy evaluation. Calling your 2nd foldr like so  `foldr (\_ x -> x) 0 [10..]` evaluates to `(\_ x -> x) *thunk* 10` and prints `10`.

Comment: @FtheBuilder Yes, the order does not matter. What matters is whether an argument is forced/demanded/needed. For instance, pattern matching (`case`) and basic operators (`==,+,*,...`) can force an argument. This makes `(\x -> 4)` and `(\x -> x*0 + 4)` different functions: the latter will evaluate `x` unlike the former.

Comment: @mucaho @chi - Your examples were really clarifying for me, because certainly the differences between `(\x -> 4)` and `(\x -> x*0 + 4)`, aren't mere details: if x is a complex "thing" to be evaluated the former way will avoid useless computations.

Answer (score 2):

The non-empty case of `foldr` can be defined as `foldr f init (x:xs) = f x (foldr f init xs)`. In your case `f` is `(\(k,v) acc -> if key == k then Just v else acc)`, so `(k,v)` stands for the current element in the list and `acc` stands for `(foldr f init xs)`. That is, `acc` stands for the recursive call. In the `then`-case, you do not use `acc`, therefore the recursive call does not happen since Haskell is lazy meaning arguments aren't evaluated until (and unless) used.

Comment: What do you mean by "The non-empty case of `foldr`"? Your answer also was quite helpful for me, thanks!

Comment: @FtheBuilder The definition of `foldr` consists of two cases: one for the empty list (`foldr _ init [] = init`) and one for non-empty lists (`foldr f init (x:xs) = f x (foldr f init xs)`). Since the former wasn't relevant to the question, I only talked about the latter case. That's what I meant by "the non-empty case".

Comment: Thank you, now your answer is completely clear for me!